# Nested CONCAT_WS throws #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row error

Tags: mysql, sql

let's suppose table t as the follwing:

t table:

```
a   b   c   d   e
a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  
a2  b2  c2  d2  e2
a3  b3  c3  d3  e3
.   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .
```

this query throws an #1242 error:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS( '*', (SELECT CONCAT_WS( '_', a, b, c) FROM t)) AS test
```

Expected result is:

```
test
a1_b1_c1*a2_b2_c2*a3_b3_c3*.....
```

What's the best woraround?

Comment: Show your [table structure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-create-table.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "t" has more than one row.  Perhaps you want one of the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS( '*', (SELECT CONCAT_WS( '_', a, b, c) FROM t limit 1)) AS test
```

or

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS( '*', (SELECT max(CONCAT_WS( '_', a, b, c)) FROM t)) AS test
```

Oops, I missed the expected results in the question.  You want:

```
select group_concat(vals SEPARATOR '*' ORDER BY t.id)
from (select concat_ws('_', a, b, c) as vals
      from t
     ) t
```

(This assumes that there is a column called "id" for ordering the results.  If not, leave out the order by clause.)

Comment: I say do it in two steps.  Implode the columns then use GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: The third Option Gordon Linoff Provides does exactly what i needed thank u Gordon

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempFoo (
    col1 varchar(250) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tempFoo (SELECT CONCAT_WS( '_', a, b, c) as r FROM t);

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col1 separator '*') FROM tempFoo;
```

Comment: yeah this works too but gordon solution doesn't need to create a temporary table thanks ficuscr